# How do i Normalize this table

Tags: database

I have a database that stores thousands of bookmarks and the table BM_Table has following columns

```
Name  Location
```

Since multiple same names has different location and multiple different names has same location.

Someone suggested me to normalize the relation to avoid this duplication of values.

But as you can see the no attribute `Name` or `Location` can be used as a primary key only candidate key is formed

So how can I normalize the table ?

Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose whoever suggested this to you meant for you to create three tables:

```
tbl_name (name_id, name)
tbl_location (locaiton_id, location)
tbl_name_location (name_id, location_id)
```

and use `tbl_name_location` to bind the other two together.

This approach will create some 'artificial' ids which you will only use to relate one table to another. As long as you will save some space for multiple name and location entries, the question is: will this be beneficial to you? It's hard to tell without knowing how you will use this database. Every request will require some joins after normalization so I suppose benchmarking and profiling would be a best way to determine if you gain anything by normalization.

Comment: but how do i assign values to NameID and LocationID.

Comment: Simple auto increment should suffice. As long as those are unique you will be able to reference table rows by using their respective ids.

Comment: Normalization doesn't have anything to do with adding id numbers. The original table was already in 5NF. Foreign key references to it require exactly *zero* joins to get the whole row. Your approach requires two joins for one table. Build all your tables like this, and query on five of them, and you're talking about 5 to 15 possibly unnecessary joins. You *definitely* want to benchmark decisions like that.

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash:Thanks RandomWhiteTrash but i would like to know the query to create the tables. Specially for creating tbl_name_location (name_id, location_id)
with name_id and location_id from tbl_name and tbl_location respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If your table is like this one (guessing at data types)

```
create table your-table-name
  name varchar(10) not null,
  location varchar(10) not null,
  primary key (name, location)
);
```

then it's already in 5NF.

Some people don't like text; they'd rather replace strings with id numbers. (Replacing strings with id numbers has nothing to do with normalization.) But every query that uses such tables requires at least one join--usually several--to recover the text from the id number.

Comment: But this does not avoid the duplication of values. doen't it?

Comment: @StevieG: that means the tuples (Hi google.com) and (Hi yahoo.com) would not be inserted ?

Comment: @sam: *Redundancy*, which is what I think you're talking about, has to do with columns, not rows. Replacing strings with numbers (which, I'll repeat, has *nothing* to do with normalization) will just repeat the numbers row by row instead of repeating strings row by row.

Answer (score -1):

table 1:
NameID
Name

table 2:
LocationID
Location

table 3:
NameToLocationID
NameID
LocationID

> In the design of a relational database management system (RDBMS), the process of organizing data to minimize redundancy is called normalization. The goal of database normalization is to decompose relations with anomalies in order to produce smaller, well-structured relations. Normalization usually involves dividing large tables into smaller (and less redundant) tables and defining relationships between them. The objective is to isolate data so that additions, deletions, and modifications of a field can be made in just one table and then propagated through the rest of the database via the defined relationships.

[Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: -1: Replacing strings with numbers has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: there is no way to use NameID and LocationID. Is there?

Comment: i look forward to seeing your response to the question @Catcall.  Please do enlighten me...

Comment: @sdology: I think the point @Catcall is making is that, assuming (name,location) is already a primary key i.e. there are no duplicate combinations, then the table is already normalized. Splitting it into 3 doesn't really serve any purpose, as the junction table would be the same size as the current table anyway..

Comment: @sdology:Thanks sdology but i would like to know the query to create the tables. Specially for creating tbl_name_location (name_id, location_id) with name_id and location_id from tbl_name and tbl_location respectively.

Comment: then maybe you shouldn't have accepted the answer you accepted?  or ask another question ... or google :)